# Basis extension theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that this question is not about basis extension theorem, but don't know the name of it.

So, the question is:

$V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space, and its bases $\mathfrak{B, C}$ are given.

If $\{v_{1}, \cdots, v_{r}\}\subseteq \mathfrak{B}$, I want to show that there exists $\{w_{1}, \cdots, w_{s}\}\subseteq \mathfrak{C}$ such that $\{v_{1}, \cdots, v_{r}, w_{1}, \cdots, w_{s}\}$ is a basis of $V$.

Basis extension theorem does not guarantee that extended basis is equal to $\mathfrak{C}$. I couldn't come up with another way. :(

Comment: What have you tried? How did the problem come up? Please add more context.

Comment: It's an exercise problem in a textbook that I'm studying now. I've tried to show that (i) it is contradiction that there doesn't exist such subset of C, (ii) there exists some subset of C that spans exactly same vector space to span{v1, ..., vr}. And all trials failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some inductive-like argument here can help. Try to understand and make formal the following arguments:

Suppose first there is no $\;w\in C\;$ such that $\;\{v_1,...,v_r, w\}\;$ is lin. ind.

This means that

$$\forall\,w\in C\;,\;\;w\in Span\{v_1,...,v_r\}\implies C\in Span\;\{v_1,...,v_r\}\implies$$

$$\implies V=Span\,C\subset Span\{v_1,...,v_r\}\implies\{v_1,...,v_r\}=B$$

and there's nothing to prove.

Thus we can assume there is  $\;w_1\in C\;$ such that $\;\{v_1,...,v_r, w_1\}\;$ is lin. ind.

Now repeat the above arguments with $\;\{v_1,...,v_r, w_1\}\;$ insted of $\;\{v_1,...,v_r\}\;$ ...